# Row header in separate row

Tags: html, html-table, semantics, semantic-markup

I know this is semantically valid HTML (validated at W3C), but the question is does it make logical sense? Does the th with the name apply as a header to the cells in the next row?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">John Baker</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>US</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The effect I want is having the name as a title for the rest of the data, and have it on a separate row in the table.

Or should I just keep them in the same row and move the th to a separate line with CSS?

Comment: Does it look like you expect? `<th>` is essentially nothing more than bold `<td>`.

Comment: I does look like I expect. Styling wise is is nothing more than a bold td, but I want the semantics right. To support things like screen readers.

Comment: Semantically it doesn't make sense. `th` is meant for the heading of a column, what you're putting in it is actually a property of the row.

Comment: @StephanMuller you are right, it is the property. I added a new hidden th in the thead and used a td in the row instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<th>` is specific to the `<tbody>` (remember, you can have multiple `<tbody>`s per `<table>`) then the semantically correct thing to do is to give it a [`scope` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-th-scope):

```
<th colspan="3" scope="rowgroup">John Baker</th>
```

Alternatively, if you want to define specific cells as being headed by a specific `<th>` then you can use the [`headers` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-headers):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="header-country">Country</th>
            <th id="header-age">Age</th>
            <th id="header-sex">Sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" id="header-1">John Baker</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="header-country header-1">US</td>
            <td headers="header-age header-1">27</td>
            <td headers="header-sex header-1">Male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```